# parameter passing by HTTP GET request other than as query parameters- slug/cleanurl/prettyurl

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-get

*Note: The URL, code used here is only for demonstration purpose of my example.*

I have seen that, For a **`HTTP GET`** request, if you want to pass a value for decision making, it is NOT passed through query String parameters for some good reasons.

Lets' say there's a thumbnail image showing a bookstore in `houston` location,  say "`ABC Bookstore`"
The `href` attribute of that image is assumed as below

```
domain.com/texas/abcbookstore-houston
```

This is what is needed, and the page shows the book store details, **instead** of the URL being shown as `domain.com/texas/details.php?id=1`

**Question:**

Any ideas how the URL is analysed to fetch the key? One website when I looked at Network tab of Chrome, it showed

```
Request Headers
:authority:www.domain.com
:method:GET
:path:/texas/abcbookstore-houston
```

**My thoughts:**

I can extract the last word after parsing the complete URL, and I get '`abcbookstore-houston`'

**Code I tried:**

```
$url = "domain.com/texas/abcbookstore-houston";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
//echo $path;//// prints "/texas/abcbookstore-houston"

$parts = explode('/', rtrim($path, '/'));
$id_str = array_pop($parts);
echo $id_str; // prints abcbookstore-houston
```

My thinking is that we can have one more column in the main `bookstore` table called '`nameofid`' and a query will fetch the '`id`' whose '`nameofid`' matches.
`nameofid` in this case is "`abcbookstore-houston`".

**Summarized Question:** Is this a correct approach? I have seen that in many of the websites, they no longer pass the query parameters even if that's a `GET` request, instead the URL looks clean like in this use-case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, since it is asking if working code is the correct approach, this is a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: You are very much confusing `pretty url`'s that require server routing config with query string params. They both do essentially the same thing

Comment: Short answer is `htaccess` will be set to send anything that doesn't have a matching directory or file to `index.php` which then would need to manage what happens based on the url segments.

Comment: @Quentin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204124/can-we-move-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review When you're flagging it, can you please choose the "other" option so that you can specify which other site you think the question should be migrated to and why you think it's a good fit for that site.  Thanks for mentioning about code-review site. Didn't know about that

Comment: @charlietfl You're giving me a very useful info.. "pretty url's that require server routing config with query string params" .. Even I noticed some links were actually having query string params, and that is analysed to redirect the user to this pretty url, and the pretty url is analysed to load the page details..Will check on to more from your comment

Comment: @charlietfl I have an understanding of using htaccess and I am re-directing user to index.php in case of unmatching file/directory request. But how is this related to `htaccess` configuration..can you share some links

Comment: should be able to find plenty in a google search for variations of `php pretty url htaccess` .

Comment: sure, thank you, I think tha'ts the correct approach or answer. @charlietfl, you can post an answer to recommend usage of php pretty url htaccess ,and I'll accept that. Already googling with "php pretty url htaccess" is giving me what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: also would suggest looking at various php routers and/or frameworks that will do all the url work for you

Comment: wow, thank you again for mentioning this

Comment: @charlietfl I have found out the solution and implemented, working great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@charlietfl* mentioned, I was actually looking at **Clean URLs** also called **Pretty URLs**

This is the actual book store details page

```
http://www.domain.com/texas/details.php?id=1
```

Basically this should be

```
http://www.domain.com/texas/details.php?id=abcbookstore-houston
```

I wanted this to be displayed in the address bar as

```
http://www.domain.com/texas/abcbookstore-houston
```

Finally, I found out the **solution** by making the below changes in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:texas/)?([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The final command can be replaced by

```
RewriteRule ^texas/([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

if '`texas`' is *mandatory* and not *optional*.

So what is actually happening here is when I search for this URL  `http://www.domain.com/texas/abcbookstore-houston` , the server is actually routing to `http://www.domain.com/texas/details.php?id=abcbookstore-houston` while we see only `http://www.domain.com/texas/abcbookstore-houston` in the address bar.

So inside `details.php` we can get the `id` using `$_GET["id"]` and continue our business logic.

---

*Additional Notes:*

If the objective was `http://www.domain.com/abcbookstore-houston`
then the RewriteRule would be

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here's more explanation about the command used

- `RewriteEngine On` turns the engine on.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` does not rewrite anything if the request filename exists, and is a file.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` does not rewrite anything if the request filename exists, and is a directory.
- `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]` This is the actual rewrite rule. It takes anything after the domain name (anything other than forward slashes), and rewrites it to `details.php`, passing it as the `id` parameter.
- `RewriteRule ^texas/([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` This is the actual rewrite rule. It takes anything after {the domain name followed by the string '`texas`'} (anything other than forward slashes), and rewrites it to `details.php`, passing it as the `id` parameter.

Note:

The technical term for word used in this use-case `abcbookstore-houston` is **slug**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug

A slug is the part of a URL which identifies a page using human-readable keywords.

> To make the URL easier for users to type, special characters are often
>   removed or replaced as well. For instance, accented characters are
>   usually replaced by letters from the English alphabet; punctuation
>   marks are generally removed; and spaces (which have to be encoded as
>   %20 or +) are replaced by dashes (-) or underscores (_), which are
>   more aesthetically pleasing.